# how to convert request.url to String

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, url, query-string

For the string, `"http://localhost:9090/calculator?oper=add&n1=10&n2=20",`

```
console.log(url.parse(req.url).query);
// gives `oper=add&n1=10&n2=20`
```

whereas

```
console.log(querystring.parse(req.url));
// gives { '/calculator?oper': 'add', n1: '10', n2: '20' }`
```

However, I'm not able to split it as these are objects, and not Strings. How do I convert them to strings?

Comment: I think `request.url` is already a string, why do you want to convert it to a string? The output of `querystring.parse(req.url)` is already splited, why do you want to split it? What output are you expecting?

Comment: @Volune : Thanks, yes request.url is a string indeed, I was confused, sorry.

>The output of querystring.parse(req.url) is already splited
But  how do I access the zero'th object of this array ?{ '/calculator?oper': 'add', n1: '20', n2: '10' } 

I can access the n1 and n2 elements as follows. 
`code`var temp = querystring.parse(req.url);
console.log(temp.n1);
console.log(temp.n2);

But as I said, I'm unable to access the zero'th object.

PS : I'm having a tough time trying to wrap in code and make bold etc. Can someone point me to a link where I can learn these for Stack Overflow

Comment: Please try to clarify your question with what you just said, and fix your question's title.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in what you provided, `querystring.parse(req.url)` mixed the url path with the key of the *zero'th value*. This means that `querystring.parse` should not be called on a full url, but only on the *query* part of the url. You can do that by using `querystring.parse` on the result of `url.parse`:

```
var parsedUrl = url.parse(testUrl); //would be url.parse(req.url)
var parsedQuery = querystring.parse(parsedUrl.query);
```

Now you can do `parsedQuery.oper`, `parsedQuery.n1`, `parsedQuery.n2`

[Example](http://ideone.com/s3iqtv)

---

If for some reason you want to iterate the parsedQuery (for example if you don't know the keys are `oper`, `n1`, `n2`, ...), you can do it this way:

```
var parsedQueryKeys = Object.keys(parsedQuery);
parsedQueryKeys.forEach(function(key) {
    console.log( key, parsedQuery[key] );
});
```

(There are multiple other solutions to iterate an object)

---

Finally, some libraries automate the parsing for you, so you can directly ask for the query values.

For example, with [express](http://expressjs.com/)'s [`req.param`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.param):

```
console.log( req.param('oper'), req.param('n1'), req.param('n2') );
```

[Find express on npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express)

Comment: Thanks volune, I was able to try out your examples. I was also able to do it passing using the second argument of url.parse as true. See code  : var temp = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
        console.log(temp.oper);
        console.log(temp.n1);
        console.log(temp.n2);

The question in the previous reply on how to access the zero'th object of {'/calculator?oper': 'add', n1: '20', n2: '10' } was just for the purpose of learning in case I run into something similar in future. Is it possible to access it using location, like [0]? Tried, couldn't get it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Try things like `temp['/calculator?oper']` or `temp[Object.keys(temp)[0]]`. But I don't recommend the second one, I think javascript objects are not expected to be ordered.

Comment: What is `querystring`, is it JS built in?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `object.toString()` to convert any variable into a string. Most scalar types and arrays will be converted. Other objects might need to have the method implemented, otherwise they will just return the text `[Object]` or something.

The second case it looks like `console.log()` used `JSON.stringify(object)`, probably because the object doesn't have a method `toString()` implemented.